# unable to maintain websocket in service worker after page closed

Tags: reactjs, websocket, push-notification, service-worker

I use websocket in service-worker. it works well while the web page is open, but if web page is closed, websocket disconnect and stop work, which confused me.

In fact because located in China, I cannot use google FCM and PUSH api, so I want to use websocket to push message.

My program was built under Create-react-app

```
//serviceWorker.js
const WebSocketConnect = () => {
  let ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/news/")
  ws.onopen = function() {
      setInterval(() => {
          if ( 'readyState' in ws && ws.readyState === 1 ) {
              ws.send('Hay')
          }
      }, 5000)
  }

  ws.onmessage = function(e) {
      console.log('Message:', e.data)
  }

  ws.onclose = function(CloseEvent) {
      ws.close()
      console.log(`Socket is clossed, code: ${CloseEvent.code} - reason: ${CloseEvent.reason}`)
      setTimeout(() => {
          WebSocketConnect()
      }, 3000)
  }

  ws.onerror = function(err) {
      console.log(err)
      //console.error('Socket encountered error: ', err.message, 'Closing socket')
      ws.close()
  }
}

WebSocketConnect()
```

Answer (score 2):

In all likelihood your service worker is being stopped and that is closing the WebSocket.

Browsers limit how long a service worker script can run before being shutdown.  Handling events like FetchEvent, MessageEvent, PushEvent, etc will wake the worker and allow it to function until the event is processed.  Most browsers will then stop the service worker about 30 seconds after being idle.

Browsers will also timeout events held open via waitUntil() after some time in order to stop the worker.  These timeouts usually occur after around 5 minutes in most browsers.

Browsers generally try harder to stop the service worker when there are no open windows for the site since running in the background can be abused.

I don't believe the web platform currently has a capability to run something like WebSocket in the background continuously without a site window open.

Comment: thx for your answer! Do u have any other idea to send message to user even without a site window open if users cannot use FCM and any other google service?

Comment: I believe push notifications are the API designed for that use case.  I'm not sure if that meets your need for not depending on a google service, though.

Comment: The same applies to air-gapped environments where not external push service can be used. Any solution to this would be quite welcome!